# Google Drive API V3, PHP Client, transfer file ownership

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a folder and change the owner using Google Drive API PHP Client. Folder gets created properly, and I can set any permission aside from owner, which returns an error. My code:

```
function createFolder($name, $parents, $mimeType)
{
    $client = getClient();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $folder->setName($name);
    if ($parents) {$folder->setParents(array($parents));}
    $folder->setMimeType($mimeType);
    $created_folder = $service->files->create($folder);
    $created_folder_id = $created_folder->getId();


    $ownerPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $ownerPermission->setEmailAddress("shared@******.com");
    $ownerPermission->setType('user');
    $ownerPermission->setRole('owner');

    $service->permissions->create($created_folder_id, $ownerPermission, array('transferOwnership' => 'true'));
    return $created_folder_id;

}
```

And the return:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "The transferOwnership parameter must be enabled when the permission role is 'owner'.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "transferOwnership"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The transferOwnership parameter must be enabled when the permission role is 'owner'."
 }
```

Am I not setting the transferOwnership parameter correctly?

Comment: have you tried $ownerPermission->setTransferOwnership(true);

Comment: I did, it returns that setTransferOwnership is an undefined method

Comment: Have you find the answer to solve your problem bro?

Comment: @HygisonBrandao yes see the last comment I wrote at the bottom, was able to answer this myself and marked it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by separating the code for creating the folder an transferring ownership. If called as part of the same `createFolder` function I get the error described above, but transferring ownership in a separate function, after folder is created, works fine.

Answer (score 2):

@DLateef If you want to make the file shareable, you may want to read more about [Permission resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions) in Drive API. For "**shared**" to be true, each file permission needs to specify a `role`, `type`, and `email address` or `domain`. As an owner of the file (Docs, Sheets, etc.), you will need to provide the appropriate permission to be set to.

Here is an example, using the [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "role": "reader",
 "type": "user",
 "emailAddress": "xxxxxxxx@xxx.com"
}
```

Response from the Drive [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?fields=appProperties%2CfileExtension%2Ckind%2CmimeType%2Cshared&key={YOUR_API_KEY}


{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
 "shared": true
}
```

However, if you are unable to switch to the Drive v3, you can still use the [Permission.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) from Drive v2 to do the job.

Or else, you can also try  `ownerPermission->setTransferOwnership(true);`